# What are advantages to prove divergence of $\sum a_n^2/n$ instead of, say $\sum a_n^2$, or even $\sum a_n$ itself?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm confused not by the following statement made in a certain book, **but why it was made**:

> If $\sum a_n^2/n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges, where $a_n>0$.

This is obvious, because if $\sum a_n$ converges ($a_n>0$), then $a_n\to 0$ and starting from some number $n>N$ we have $a_n^2<a_n$, and thus $\sum a_n^2$ converges, and definitely $\sum a_n^2/n$ converges. Thus divergence of $\sum a_n^2/n$ is much stronger and restrictive statement than divergence of $\sum a_n$.

Now, they plan to use the divergence of $\sum a_n$ to check some statements.

**Question:** Isn't it easy enough to check if $\sum a_n$ ($a_n>0$) diverges, directly without resorting to consideration of $\sum a_n^2/n$? What are advantages to use $\sum a_n^2/n$ instead of, say $\sum a_n^2$, or even $\sum a_n$ itself?

Am I missing anything simple and obvious here?

Comment: Think about a series of the form $\sum \sqrt{\mbox{ugly expression}}$, squaring $a_n$ can make it easier to handle.

Comment: But then why not square and *not* divide by $n$?

Comment: What book was it? Maybe seeing surrounding context could help.

Comment: @Sil they have a very complex series. They want simpler divergence critea, so as alternative criteria (which are easier to check) they list two criteria 1) divergence of $\sum a_n$, 2) divergence of $\sum a_n^2/n$. I don't see why even consider criteria 2). 2) is contained in 1) and it is harder tp prove than 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $a_n\not\rightarrow0$ there is nothing to show, as the statement is obvious.

If $a_n\rightarrow0$, then $a_n\geq\frac{a^2_n}{n}$ for all $n$ large enough. divergence of $\sum_n\frac{a^2_n}{n}$ then implies divergence of $\sum_na_n$ by comparison test.

As to the usefulness of that statement, it might be that the series $\sum_n\frac{a_n^2}{n}$ is easier to analyze that $\sum_na_n$.

This is a rather artificial example:

Consider $\sum_k\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log k}}$. It is easier to use the integral test on the series
$\sum_k\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{\log k}$ and check that it diverges, and so the first series diverges. Again, this is just one example. There might be others much more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that $a_n^2/n$ looks much easier than $a_n$. But in fact this statement does not seem to be very useful indeed.

Comment: Thanks. I though I was losing my sanity there. If there are no answers better than yours I will accept it.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with this question, because you consider an alternating series. But I see what you mean. Probably this is much better example: $\sum n^{-1/4}$ diverges, but $\sum n^{-3/2}$ converges. In this case the series $\sum a_n$ is useful, but $\sum a_n^2/n$ is not useful.

Comment: Yes, did not notice $a_n>0$. Your example does not illustrate the question.

Comment: @PeppaPig Your example with $n^{-1/4}$ and $n^{-3/2}$ dont prove anything. Its an affirming the consequent fallacy.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum it is a demonstration, not a proof. I said example. Does everybody on this forum need to learn to read?